# MySQL Join Performance

Tags: mysql, performance, join

The following query below executes in 17 seconds in a view.  There are 450,000 rows.  I have an index on the two columns being joined and they are FK.  The join columns are BIGINTS.  Is there anyway to speed this guy up?

```
SELECT c.id, sce.user_id
FROM sims_classroom c
JOIN sims_class_enrollment sce ON c.id = sce.classroom_id
```

**EXPLAIN**

```
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'c', 'index', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '8', NULL, '211213', 'Using index'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'sce', 'ref', 'fk_class_enrollment_classroom_id', 'fk_class_enrollment_classroom_id', '9', 'ngsp.c.id', '1', 'Using where'
```

**ROWS**

```
sims_classroom = 200100
sims_class_enrollment = 476396
```

Comment: Use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) on your query, and give us the output.

Comment: How many rows in `sims_classroom` and `sims_class_enrollment` too

Comment: Could you also try profiling your query?  `SET PROFILING = 1; SELECT ...; SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1; SET PROFILING = 0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will slow down writes a little but since you're only one column short of having everything you need in your index, I would do a two column index for sce:

```
classroom_id, user_id
```

This would result in mysql not even needing to go to the actual table (both would be 'Using index' in the explain).